# Why does adding an existing repo as a submodule modify .git/config?

Tags: git, addition, git-submodules

If I add a submodule that does not currently exist, no submodule information is added to `.git/config`.

```
$ mkdir testing
$ cd testing
$ git init
$ git submodule add git@git.server:submodule.git
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
```

However, if I add a repo that currently exists as a submodule, the url is added to `.git/config`:

```
$ mkdir testing
$ cd testing
$ git init
$ git clone git@git.server:submodule.git
$ git submodule add git@git.server:submodule.git
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
[submodule "submodule"]
    url = git@git.server:submodule.git
```

I would have assumed that in both cases, `git submodule add` would have only modified `.gitmodules`, and that `git submodule init` would have updated the project's `.git/config`.

Why is `.git/config` modified in the second case but not the first?  Can somebody explain the rational for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was fixed in https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cd9de3e18183422cd7ec3cd81cebc656068ea42

Answer (score 4):

This does seem strange.  That behaviour was introduced [in this commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2f939170c65173076bbd752bb3c764536b3b09b):

```
commit c2f939170c65173076bbd752bb3c764536b3b09b
Author: Mark Levedahl <mlevedahl@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Jul 9 21:05:41 2008 -0400

    git-submodule - register submodule URL if adding in place

    When adding a new submodule in place, meaning the user created the
    submodule as a git repo in the superproject's tree first, we don't go
    through "git submodule init" to register the module.  Thus, the
    submodule's origin repository URL is not stored in .git/config, and no
    subsequent submodule operation will ever do so.  In this case, assume the
    URL the user supplies to "submodule add" is the one that should be
    registered, and do so.

    Signed-off-by: Mark Levedahl <mlevedahl@gmail.com>
    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

*Update: you've pointed out in the comments below that my original interpretation of this commit message didn't make any sense, so I've removed that text now to avoid confusion for others.*

As mentioned in the comments below, [cdwilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162349/cdwilson) posted to the git mailing list to ask about this inconsistency, and as a result Jens Lehman is working on a fix - that thread can be found here:

- http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Why-does-adding-an-existing-repo-as-a-submodule-modify-git-config-td6392263.html

Comment: Mark, thanks for the pointer to that commit (at least it shows this behavior is intentional).  However, I'm still confused when you said "it isn't cloned until the submodule is updated".  In the first case above, `git submodule add git@git.server:submodule.git` actually clones `submodule.git` into the super-project.  In the examples above, the only submodule command I ran was `git submodule add`, and in both cases I ended up with a cloned submodule.git in my super-project.  The only difference is what `.git/config` looks like afterwards, and case #1 also needs `git submodule init` to register.

Comment: This behavior would make sense to me if, in the first case, `git submodule add` didn't clone the repository until the submodule was registered (`git submodule init`) and updated (`git submodule update`).  However, since case #1 above actually does clone `submodule.git`, and requires `git submodule init` to register, I would expect case #2 to require `git submodule init` as well to perform the registration.  I'm sure there is just something here that I'm missing, but right now I don't understand why there is a discrepancy.

Comment: @cdwilson: Good point, I was misremembering the behaviour of `git submodule add` in my rush to answer the question.  I'll correct my answer.  You could ask about this on the git mailing list for a proper answer - I suspect this is a bug, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: posted to git mailing list http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/174199